# How to render drawer results within the <main> tag?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I get the Link from the `<MenuItem>`  to render within `<main>` . I have been trying this for a long time now and can't seem to find an answer. 
Here is the code Hope my problem is understandable. A link to a working example or so would also be fine.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
render() {
    const { classes, children } = this.props;
    const { mobileOpen} = this.state;

    const drawer = (
      <div>
        <Hidden smDown>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        </Hidden>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem component={Link} to="/">
          Home

          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem component={Link} to="/PatientdataPatient" >
          Users
          </MenuItem>

        </MenuList>


      </div>
    );

    return (

      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>


         ......code


            <Drawer
              container={this.props.container}
              variant="temporary"
              open={mobileOpen}
              onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
              variant="permanent"
              open
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
        </nav>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          {children}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of potential ways to do this. What it comes down to is that the link should somehow change props or state that impact what you display in `<main>`. Is `Link` in your code a `react-router` Link? If so, the [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) examples are a good place to start.

Comment: Ok thanks will go through that